# C# calling unmanaged code. Does the ref-keyword fix memory location of variable?

Tags: c#, c, unmanaged

when calling unmanaged code from C# I often see memory pinned (which I understand why we do that) but I also see the ref-keyword being used. Now, I wonder why wouldn't we here need some memory pinning as well?

*Edit*: for simplicity let's assume the external code *does not* store the pointers for later use.

```
internal class Program
{
    // extern void multiply(BoxT * box, const double O[3]);
    [DllImport("vectorMaths.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void multiply(ref BoxT box, double[] O);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct BoxT
    {
        public double[] O; // origin of box in coordinate system
        public double[] A; // adjacent corner 1
        public double[] B; // adjacent corner 2
        public double[] C; // adjacent corner 3
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create box
        var BoxT = new BoxT
        {
            O = new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, // origin of box in coordinate system
            A = new double[] { 2, 1, 1 }, // adjacent corner 1
            B = new double[] { 1, 2, 1 }, // adjacent corner 2
            C = new double[] { 1, 1, 2 }, // adjacent corner 3
        };
        var deformation = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        // call C function to deform box. Wouldn't I need to pin memory locations here?
        multiply(ref BoxT, deformation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked some of the other questions on this site? Looks like e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776096/pin-data-for-p-invoke-access might give you what you need.

Comment: I'm more concerned by the use of arrays - that *will not* work well here; did you perhaps intend for those to be "fixed buffers" ?

Comment: my *understanding* is that if you use `ref Foo` (rather than `Foo*`), the runtime (or the AOT, as appropriate) adds the equivalent of a `fixed` block against the `ref`, and passes the *unmanaged reference* (i.e. the pinned value) to the API; does that make sense?

Comment: (running a mangled version of your code through `[LibraryImport(...)]` instead of `[DllImport(...)]` supports this view)

Comment: I agree - this code is unsafe because of the arrays and may only be working through blind luck (and there may be tears before bedtime).

Comment: What is the C definition of BoxT? Note that `multiply(ref BoxT box, double[] O);` should probably be `multiply(ref BoxT box, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)] double[] O);`

Comment: Your box looks weird, you would typically describe an axis aligned box with a position and a size. You typically also want to use a point/vector type to describe position/size, instead of arrays. There are also .net libraries to do most kinds of vector math, so I would not use P/Invoke unless I really had to. Transforming a box seem very trivial to do with just some basic linear algebra knowledge.

Comment: It is the job of the pinvoke marshaller to ensure that unmanaged code sees stable objects.  It certainly does so here without you having to help, it needs to convert the BoxT object because of the embedded arrays and that converted object is allocated in memory that is not subject to garbage collection.  The only time that pinning is relevant is when the unmanaged code stores the pointer and uses it later.  Very undesirable.

Comment: @MarcGravell After having done more research I think the use of arrays is OK because they are blittable ["As an optimization, arrays of blittable primitive types and classes that contain only blittable members are pinned instead of copied during marshalling."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types). No?

Comment: @HansPassant: That is the answer I would love to believe, however, could you elaborate why that is so or do you have some further reading for me to back this up?

Comment: @pion a naked array can be pinned and sent as-is; but you're not sending a naked array - you're sending a `Box*`, and a `Box*` *absolutely cannot* be blitted, precisely because of those arrays (which means a `Box` in the CLR contains a managed reference) - so yes, you're forcing it to be copied